# For magic items that give the user an ability boost (Str, Dex , etc), why is the first day (24 hour) benefit counts as "temporary"?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

For magic items that give the user an ability boost (Str, Dex , etc), why is the first day (24 hours) benefit counts as "temporary"?

Example: Belt of Physical Perfection:
This belt has a large platinum buckle and grants the wearer an enhancement bonus to all physical ability scores (Strength, Dexterity, and Constitution) of +2, +4, or +6. Treat this as a temporary ability bonus for the first 24 hours the belt is worn.

Is the ability boost permanent after a day?

I mean common sense should say that without the belt the user loses the ability boost. So wouldn't it be just as easy to say "so long as the user is has X /holding/wearing/using they get a temporary boosts until X is taken away, dispelled, broken, stolen... etc"?

Comment: Your body seems different from your title. Are you asking why the bonuses are "temporary" at first, or are you asking if you lose the bonuses if you take off the item?

Comment: @GreySage He's confused how it can be even more temporary than something that obviously goes away after taking it off. When in doubt, assume the asker simply hasn't managed to find or read the rules that would answer their question. (I think that part of the question should be restored; it's important for expressing the core confusion answers will need to solve.)

Comment: @Jhyarelle Also, please don't use posts on the main site to complain about a suspension. If you have questions, complaints, or other issues with moderation, or any other aspect of how the community manages the site, you can post them on [meta].

Comment: Ill take the strike, waring what ever? Ban me Ill make another account. It was SARCASM and I deleted it.

Comment: @JhyarelleSilver We're not about to suspend you for that. Thank you for removing it.

Comment: @Jhyarelle Yes, that's not suspension-worthy, that's "please use Meta for that"–worthy. (But also note that making another account won't work. Please just take the warning to heart and follow the rules.)

Comment: @sevensideddie  I feel like this might be slightly different than the linked question. Or, at least, I don't see an answer that helped explain *why* the ability changes are temporary, only a (vague) description of what a Temporary increase is and a (better) explanation of Permanent increases.

Comment: @Ifusaso Maybe, but it's on this asker to clarify their question, if so. Based on experience with the asker, their problem is much more likely just the surface confusion. (The bit about "over complicating the rules", suggesting a nuanced Q, was added to the Q by someone else, and I've removed that now.) This should be left up to the asker to make the case that they meant something deeper.

Comment: There's a good question here about designer reasons for *having* magic items grant temporary ability increases in the first 24 hours, but there's *also* the duplicate question about the *impact* of temporary ability increases in the first 24 hours. Eliminating the second, duplicated part of this question would see me vote to take this question off hold.